# Adding to integer array base address C?

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("Base Address of array = %p\n",a);
    printf("Address1 = %p \t Address2 = %p\n",a+1,&a+1);
    return 0;
}
```

In the print both the case "a" represents the base address of array,but the first one increment 4 bytes and the second by 20 bytes. Any specific reason ?

Output:

```
Base Address of array 0x7fff2059b240                                                                                                                        
Address1 = 0x7fff2059b244         Address2 = 0x7fff2059b254
```

Comment: `a` is an array, **not** a pointer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two concepts:

1. Pointer arithmetic is based on the size of the pointed-to type.  In other words, if you have a pointer to type `T`, then adding 1 to that pointer will give you the address of the next *object* of type `T`.
2. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

You declared `a` as a 5-element array of `int`.  Assuming 4-byte `int`, the array occupies 20 bytes.

The *expression* `a` "decays" to type `int *`, so adding 1 to it gives you the address of the next `int` object following `a` (IOW, it's the same as `&a[1]`).

The expression `&a` has type `int (*)[5]` (pointer to 5-element array of `int`), so adding 1 to it gives you the address of the next *5-element array of `int`*.

Answer (score 1):

The size of what `&a` points to is 20 bytes (the whole array: 4 bytes x 5 elements), while the size of what `a` points to is 4 bytes (a single `int`).  The fact that they are both at the same address is irrelevant; they are different ways of interpreting what is at that address.

Comment: So you meant that "a" is  integer pointer and if &a is used the pointer will be treated as pointer to an array

Comment: `a` is a pointer to the first element of an integer array (and thus a pointer to an integer), while `&a` is a pointer the the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

When you increment `a+1` `a` is actually a pointer to `int` so its incremented `4` bytes, that is the size of int. But when you do `&a`, it becomes address of an array of `5` ints, so if you increment that, you will skip size of array of 5 ints.